# How to dynamically append more information to a useState Array in React

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to dynamically append my empty array using useState. I want the program to work in such a way that on each button click, it fetches new data and appends it to the already existing array. How do I do this. The api I'm fetching automatically has new data upon refreshing the page.

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {

  const[data, setData] = useState([]);
  let info = [];

  const handleFetch = () => {
    fetch("https://www.randomuser.me/api")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => setData(data.results));
    
  }


  const information = data.map((details) => {
    return ( 
      <>
      <h1> {details.name.title} </h1> 
      <h1> {details.name.first} </h1>
      <h1> {details.name.last} </h1>
      <img src = {details.picture.large}/>
      </>
      )
  })

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick = {handleFetch}>Fetch New Details</button>
      <div>{information}</div>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First*, don't shadow the variable.  Use a different variable name in your API response handler so you can access both.  So instead of this:

```
.then((data) => setData(data.results));
```

Something like this:

```
.then((newData) => setData(newData.results));
```

*Then* you can merge the two arrays when setting state.  For example, you can `concat` the arrays:

```
setData(data.concat(newData.results))
```

Comment: ok, so I did that and then this happened: TypeError
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')

Comment: Ok so it turns out the second method you posted doesn't work for some reason but the first does. Do you know why?

Comment: @youngprogrammer1997: I do not, though certainly I can't fully test this in your scenario.  It's possible I overlooked something in the second, but if the first is working then I can simply remove the second from the answer.